# Fibonacci direct calculation formula

Tags: python, math, fibonacci

I have seen  Fibonacci has direct formula with this `(Phi^n)/√5` 
while I am getting results in same time but accurate result not approximate with something I managed to write:

```
for r = 0 to 2 Sum [(n-r)!/((n-2r)!r!)]
```

(`!` is the symbol for *factorial* ):

```
def fr(n, p):
    # (n-r)!/((n-2r)!r!)
    r = int(n / p)
    n_f = 0
    for j in range(1, r + 1):
        t_f = 1
        r_f = factorial(j)
        i = (n - j)

        while i > (n - (2 * j)):
            t_f = t_f * i
            i = i - 1

        n_f = n_f + t_f / r_f

    return n_f + 1

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n - 1)
```

so for 12 we can do `fr(11, 2)`
also `(Phi12)/√5 = 144.0013888754932` rounds to `Fib(12) =144`

I don't understand why `(n-r)!/((n-2r)!r!)` is fast

Comment: Your indentation is off, you do not show an import for `factorial`, and your routine requires *two* parameters, neither of which is explained. What is the meaning of `p`? How do you know that `n=11` and `p=2` for the 12th Fibonacci number?

Comment: add code for factorial . also  p is always 2 here i ran the code against standard Fibonacci  code and its producing same result

Comment: How exactly do you measure that it is "faster"? What exactly do you compare it to? For what values? Also your code looks like Python so it probably makes sense to add that as a tag.

Comment: For how large n are you interested in Fib(n)?

Comment: sorry for not including python tag , also its faster than DP solution but same with (Phi^n)/√5 in time . but with this we can get exact number and with (Phi^n)/√5 its approximation

Comment: for n ranging 100 i checked this form 100 to 1000 i did approximation check

Comment: why did you down-voted it i have simple curiosity that i didn't find such solution online so i thought i can discuss it here

Comment: How do you calculate phi^n? With `pow`, I get that it is much faster.

Comment: if you say A is faster than B, you should include your timings for A and B  and explanation of how you perform the timing.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but since it's about math more than programming, I think you'll get more relevant responses at math.stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binet's formula for the nth Fibonacci number is as follows:

```
def binet(n):
    phi = (1 + 5**.5) / 2
    psi = (1 - 5**.5) / 2
    return (phi**n - psi**n) / 5**.5
```

This formula is mathematically exact, but in practice it is subject to floating point error. The term psi**n converges rapidly to zero as n increases, so it can be omitted when n is large. This yields your approximate formula.

Binet's formula is very fast. On my machine, it computes the 1000th Fibonacci number in about 400 nanoseconds.

```
In [21]: %timeit binet(1000)
426 ns ± 24.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

The binomial sum formula for Fibonacci numbers is very interesting. It says that Fibonacci numbers are sums along shallow diagonals of Pascal's triangle, as shown in this figure.
[image: Fibonacci numbers in Pascal's triangle]

This formula works because each diagonal is the sum of the two previous diagonals, just as every term in the Fibonacci sequence is the sum of the two previous terms. For example, the ninth and tenth diagonals can be added to obtain the eleventh diagonal.

```
    1 +  7 + 15 + 10 + 1 = 34
1 + 8 + 21 + 20 +  5     = 55
-----------------------------
1 + 9 + 28 + 35 + 15 + 1 = 89
```

However, this formula is not fast at all. It *seems* fast because computers can perform millions of calculations per second. My machine needs 84 ms to calculate the 1000th Fibonacci number using your code. This is 200,000 times longer than it takes using Binet's formula.

```
 In [22]: %timeit fr(1001, 2)
 84 ms ± 875 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```