# Prolog, Dynamic Programming, Fibonacci series

Tags: prolog, logic, fibonacci

I should preface this by saying this is a homework problem that I am having issues with, and Im not sure if that sort of thing is allowed around here, but I dont know where else to turn to. This is the question I've been asked:

> In the sample code for this question, you can see a Fibonacci predicate `fibSimple/2` which calculates the Fibonacci of X, a natural number. The problem with the naive recursive solution, is that you end up recalculating the same recursive case several times. See here for an explanation.
>
> For example, working out the fib(5) involves working out the solution for fib(2) three separate times. A Dynamic Programming approach can solve this problem. Essentially, it boils down to starting with fib(2), then calculating fib(3), then fib(4) etc.... until you reach fib(X). You can store these answers in a list, with fib(X) ending up as the first item in the list.
>
> Your base cases would look like the following:

```
fib(0,[0]).
fib(1,[1,0]).
```

> Note the way that fib(1) is defined as [1,0]. fib(1) is really 1 but we are keeping a list of previous answers.
>
> Why do we do this? Because to calculate fib(X), we just have to calculate fib(X-1) and add the first two elements together and insert them at the front of the list. For example, from the above, it is easy to calculate fib(2,Ans). fib(2) in this case would be [1,1,0]. Then fib(3) would be [2,1,1,0], fib(4) would be [3,2,1,1,0] etc....
>
> Complete the fib/2 predicate as outlined above - the base cases are shown above. You need to figure out the one line that goes after the base cases to handle the recursion.

This is the sample code they provided

```
fibSimple(0,0). % fib of 0 is 0
fibSimple(1,1). % fib of 1 is 1
fibSimple(N,X) :- N>1,fibSimple(N-1,A), fibSimple(N-2,B), X is A+B.

fib(0,[0]).
fib(1,[1,0]).
```

I've had a few attempts at this, and while I'm fairly certain my attempt will end up being hopelessly wrong, this is what I have most recently tried

```
fib(X,[fib(X-2)+fib(X-1) | _]).
```

My reasoning to this is that if you can get the answer to the last 2, and add them together making them the first or "head" of the list, and then the underscore representing the rest.

My 2 issues are:

***1)*** I don't know/think this underscore will do what I want it to do, and am lost in where to go from here
 and

***2)*** I don't know how to even run this program as the `fib\2` predicate requires 2 parameters. And lets say for example I wanted to run `fib\2` to find the fibonacci of 5, I would not know what to put as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: For yet another approach using `assert` directly: [Why this dynamic version of Fibonacci program is incredibly faster then this other? Prolog solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358747/why-this-dynamic-version-of-fibonacci-program-is-incredibly-faster-then-this-oth). This is basically a "self-modifying program", using the Prolog database as cache. Not the path I would take, but definitely a solution.

Comment: I have replaced my previous horrible wall-of-text answer with something much nicer and digestible [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers): a list of various approaches to compute Fibonacci series.

Answer (score 3):

Because this is homework I will only sketch the solution - but it should answer the questions you asked.

A predicate differs from a function in that it has no return value. Prolog just tells you if it can derive it (*). So if you just ask if `fib(5)` is true the best you can get is "yes". But what are the Fibonacci numbers from 1 to 5 then? That's where the second argument comes in. Either you already know and check:

```
?- fib(5, [5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0]).
true ;                   <--- Prolog can derive this fact. With ; I see more solutions.
false                    <--- no, there are no other solutions
```

Or you leave the second argument as a variable and Prolog will tell you what values that variable must have such that it can derive your query:

```
?- fib(5, X).
X = [5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

So the second argument contains the result you are looking for.

You can also ask the other queries like `fib(X,Y)` "which numbers and their fibonacci hostories can we derive?" or `fib(X, [3 | _])` "which number computes the  the fibonacci number 3?". In the second case, we used the underscore to say that the rest of the list does not matter. (2)

So what do we do with `fib(X,[fib(X-2)+fib(X-1) | _]).`? If we add it to the clauses for 0 and 1 you were given we can just query all results:

```
?- fib(X,Y).
X = 0,
Y = [1] ;    <-- first solution X = 0, Y = [1]
X = 1,
Y = [1, 0] ; <-- second solution X = 1, Y = [1, 0]
Y = [fib(X-2)+fib(X-1)|_2088]. <-- third solution
```

The third solution just says: a list that begins with the term `fib(X-2)+fib(X-1)` is a valid solution (the `_2088` as just a variable that was not named by you). But as mentioned in the beginning, this term is not evaluated. You would get similar results by defining `fib(X, [quetzovercaotl(X-1) | _])`.

So similar to `fibSimple` you need a rule that tells Prolog how to derive new facts from facts it already knows. I have reformatted `fibSimple` for you:

```
fibSimple(N,X) :-
  N>1,
  fibSimple(N-1,A),
  fibSimple(N-2,B),
  X is A+B.
```

This says if `N > 1` and we can derive `fibSimple(N-1,A)` and we can derive `fibSimple(N-2,B)` and we can set X to the result of A + B, then we derive `fibSimple(N, X)`. The difference to what you wrote is that `fibSimple(N-1,A)` occurs in the body of the rule. Again the argument `N-1` does not get evaluated. What actually happens is that the recursion constructs the terms `3-1` and `(3-1)-1)` when called with the query `fib(3,X)`. The actual evaluation happens in the arithmetic predicates `is` and `<`. For example, the recursive predicate stops when it tries to evaluate `(3-1)-1 > 1` because `1>1` is not true. But we also do not hit the base case `fibSimple(1, 1)` because the term `(3-1)-1` is not the same as `1` even though they evaluate to the same number.

This is the reason why Prolog does not find the Fibonacci number of 3 in the simple implementation:

```
?- fibSimple(3, X).
false.
```

The arithmetic evaluation is done by the `is` predicate: the query `X is (3-1) -1` has exactly the solution `X = 1`. (3)

So `fibSimple` must actually look like this: (4)

```
fibSimple(0,1).
fibSimple(1,1).
fibSimple(N,X) :-
    N>1,
    M1 is N -1,      % evaluate N - 1
    M2 is N -2,      % evaluate N - 2
    fibSimple(M1,A),
    fibSimple(M2,B),
    X is A+B.
```

For `fib` you can use this as a template where you only need one recursive call because both `A` and `B` are in the history list. Be careful with the head of your clause: if `X` is the new value it can not also be the new history list. For example, the head could have the form `fib(N, [X | Oldhistory])`.

Good luck with the homework!

(1) This is a little simplified - Prolog will usually give you an answer substitution that tells you what values the variables in your query have. There are also some limited ways to deal with non-derivability but you don't need that here.

(2) If you use the arithmetic predicates `is` and `>` these two queries will not work with the straightforward implementation. The more declarative way of dealing with this is [arithmetic constraints](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/clpfd).

(3) For this evaluation to work, the right hand side of `is` may not contain variables. This is where you would need the arithmetic constraints from (2).

(4) Alternatively, the base cases could evaluate the arithmetic terms that were passed down:

```
fibSimple(X, 0) :-
    0 is X.
fibSimple(X, 1) :-
    1 is X.
fibSimple(N,X) :-
    N>1,
    fibSimple(N-1,A),
    fibSimple(N-2,B),
    X is A+B.
```

But this is less efficient because a single number takes much less space than the term `100000 - 1 - 1 -1 .... -1`.