# First N Fibonacci Numbers in Prolog

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I want to generate the 1st N fibonacci numbers in Prolog. That means whenever I will give N = 5, it should print : 0,1,1,2,3, But whenever I run it suppose with N =5 then it gives output as : 1,2,1,3,1,2,5.

Below is my program:

```erlang
fib(0,0).
fib(1,1).
fib(F,N) :-
        N>1,
        N1 is N-1,
        N2 is N-2,
        fib(F1,N1),
        fib(F2,N2),
        F is F1+F2,
        format('~w, ',[F]).
```

Comment: This computes _F = fib(N)_, not the first _N_ numbers _fib(.)_. You can obtain a list of the first _N_ fib(.)  numbers by calling the goal `bagof(F,X^(between(0,5,X),fib(F,X)),Bag).`, but look here for a less computationally expensive `fib/2`: [Prolog, Dynamic Programming, Fibonacci series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61020478/prolog-dynamic-programming-fibonacci-series)

Comment: @David Tonhofer : I saw that link, but there they are calculating the nth fibonacci number. For an example if I put N=5 there I am getting output as = 5 instead of 1,1,2,3,5

Comment: Instead of the wall of text from my previous reference, I have set up a nice tree of possible implementations [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers/README.md). Choose one!

Answer (score 4):

Just so we're all on the same page, this is what happens when running your code with `N = 5`:

```
?- fib(Fib, 5).
1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 
Fib = 5 ;
false.
```

You are trying to print results rather than computing a data structure (a list) of the results. This is almost always not the way to go in Prolog.

(As an aside, the usual order of arguments in Prolog is "inputs" first, then "outputs". I believe most Prolog programmers would expect this predicate to be `fib(N, Fib)` rather than `fib(Fib, N)`. We'll continue with your version, but it is confusing!)

One of the problems with printing intermediate results is that it can be difficult to understand which results are printed, and in which order. We can change your printing goal to be a bit more explicit about that is going on:

```
    format('computed fib(~w, ~w)~n',[F, N]).
```

This gives:

```
?- fib(Fib, 5).
computed fib(1, 2)
computed fib(2, 3)
computed fib(1, 2)
computed fib(3, 4)
computed fib(1, 2)
computed fib(2, 3)
computed fib(5, 5)
Fib = 5 ;
false.
```

As you can see, this "naive" Fibonacci computation computes intermediate results several times, which is why you get more outputs than you expected. For example (in functional notation), computing `fib(4)` will compute `fib(2)` and `fib(3)`, but computing `fib(5)` will *also* compute `fib(3)` separately.

If you remove the printing, your predicate does work correctly, for example:

```
?- fib(Fib, 4).
Fib = 3 .

?- fib(Fib, 5).
Fib = 5 .

?- fib(Fib, 6).
Fib = 8 .

?- fib(Fib, 7).
Fib = 13 .
```

There are several ways of getting the results into a list if you really want. For example, using some predicates from the SWI-Prolog library:

```
?- numlist(1, 20, Ns), maplist(fib, Fibs, Ns).
Ns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9|...],
Fibs = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34|...] ;
false.
```

There are several problems with this: Do you *really* want a list? Prolog's backtracking for computing results one after the other is often superior to computing a list of results "all at once". More importantly, this naive Fibonacci implementation is very very inefficient. The above goal takes over a second on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

From "Approach 3" on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61027299/884463), completely reviewed here:

> At
> [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Prolog),
> under Fibonacci/Prolog, the following quite interesting solution is
> given. It uses a "lazy list", which is an open list (a list where the
> termination (the "fin") is not `[]` but an unbound variable), where a
> "frozen goal" is attached to the list-terminating unbound variable using
> the predicate
> [`freeze/2`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=freeze/2).
> The frozen goal is run (a "coroutine") whenever the value of that
> unbound variable is needed.

Proceed "bottom-up" with a "lazy list" as cache. The "lazy list"
is an open list that has a frozen goal to compute the next list
entry on its "fin".

Retrieving a member of the list using `nth0(N,Cache,F)` causes unification of the unbound "fin" with a new listbox [*|*]. This
thaws the goal on the "fin", which then computes the next
Fibonacci number, unifies it with arg1 of the listbox and then
sets up a new frozen goal on arg2 of the listbox, the
% new "fin" of the lazy list.

It is not directly evident why this works with `nth0/3`, so a replacement predicate `retrieve/3` which also prints debugging messages has been provided.

Example:

```
?- debug(fib_bll).
?- fib_bottomup_lazylist_cache(10,F,Cache).

% At this point, the cache just contains [0,1|_]: [0,1|_28196]
% At K = 0, N = 10, No unfreeze at this point
% At K = 1, N = 10, No unfreeze at this point
% At K = 2, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 0, FB = 1, FIN has been unified to [1|_28628]
% At K = 3, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 1, FB = 1, FIN has been unified to [2|_28910]
% At K = 4, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 1, FB = 2, FIN has been unified to [3|_29192]
% At K = 5, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 2, FB = 3, FIN has been unified to [5|_29474]
% At K = 6, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 3, FB = 5, FIN has been unified to [8|_29756]
% At K = 7, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 5, FB = 8, FIN has been unified to [13|_30038]
% At K = 8, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 8, FB = 13, FIN has been unified to [21|_30320]
% At K = 9, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 13, FB = 21, FIN has been unified to [34|_30602]
% At K = 10, N = 10, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal
% Unfrozen: FA = 21, FB = 34, FIN has been unified to [55|_30884]
% Unfrozen: FA = 21, FB = 34, FIN has been unified to [55|_30884]
% F = 55,
% Cache = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55|_31458],
% freeze(_31458,fibonacci_algorithms:bll_frozen(34,55,_31458)).
```

Note that for call to `retrieve/3`, where `K==N`, the same debug
message is issued **twice**. This is because
`retrieve_3(K,N,[_|More],F)` is attempted first, leading to
thawing, but then a rollback is issued due to `K<N`, and the
frozen goal is reinstated. The second clause
`retrieve_3(N,N,[F|_],F)` is then attempted, leading to the same
thawing. Side-effects in Prolog: interesting.

This approach allows you to widen the cache on request, too.
For example,

This approach allows you to widen the cache on request, too. For
example, if I want *fib(10)* first, but then also *fib(13)* I can just reuse the cache, lengthening it:

```
?- 
fibb_bottomup_lazylist_cache(10,Fib10,Cache),nth0(13,Cache,Fib13).
Fib10 = 55,
Cache = [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233|_55906],
Fib13 = 233,
freeze(_55906,fibonacci_algorithms:bll_frozen(144,233,_55906)).
```

Note the residual goal being printed out.

```
% Carve the constants fib(0) and fib(1) out of the code.

const(fib0,0).
const(fib1,1).

% :- debug(fib_bll).  % Uncomment to allow debugging printout

fib_bottomup_lazylist_cache(N,F,Cache) :-
   const(fib0,F0),
   const(fib1,F1),
   Cache=[F0,F1|Fin],
   freeze(
      Fin,
      bll_frozen(F0,F1,Fin)),
   debug(fib_bll,"At this point, the cache just contains [0,1|_]: ~q",Cache),
   % nth0(N,Cache,F).  
   retrieve(N,Cache,F).

bll_frozen(FA,FB,FIN) :-
   FC is FA + FB,
   FIN=[FC|NewFIN],
   debug(fib_bll,"Unfrozen: FA = ~d, FB = ~d, FIN has been unified to ~q",[FA,FB,FIN]),
   freeze(
      NewFIN,
      bll_frozen(FB,FC,NewFIN)).

% A replacement for nth0/3 to show what's going on

retrieve(N,Cache,F) :-
   retrieve_2(0,N,Cache,F).

retrieve_2(K,N,Cache,F) :-
   (var(Cache)
    -> debug(fib_bll,"At K = ~d, N = ~d, Will call unification with a listbox that will unfreeze the goal",[K,N])
    ;  debug(fib_bll,"At K = ~d, N = ~d, No unfreeze at this point",[K,N])),
   retrieve_3(K,N,Cache,F).

retrieve_3(K,N,[_|More],F) :-
   K < N,
   !,
   Kp is K+1,
   retrieve_2(Kp,N,More,F).
retrieve_3(N,N,[F|_],F).
```

Comment: I have also created an overview of Fibonacci computation [here](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/other_notes/about_fibonacci_numbers).

Comment: Algorithm has been completely revised because I didn't even understand it myself any longer.